# Change Default directory of Documents and Settings?

Tags: windows, home-directory, folder-redirection

Let's say I have Windows installed on drive C, however I install all of my programs on the D drive, and I keep my user profile on the D drive as well (things like My Documents). How can I have Windows use those folders instead of the ones on the C drive?

Comment: Good question. Can't +1, used them all already :/

Answer (score 7):

[Here](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/moving_documents_and_settings_folder_onto_second_hard_disk.html) is a tutorial on moving the Documents and Settings folder to a second hard disk.

Excerpt:

> 1) Set up your network and your
>   network drive. Make sure that it is
>   assigned a particular letter for each
>   machine. (Assign permanent drive
>   letters under Control Panel -->
>   Administrative Tools --> Computer
>   Management --> Disk Management. This
>   should work for network drives as
>   well. Someone correct me if I'm wrong;
>   again, I haven't done this before.
>
> 2) On your computers, open Windows
>   Explorer. From My Computer ,
>   right-click on My Documents and select
>   properties. The first thing that pops
>   up is a "target folder location"
>   screen. Select "move" and pick the
>   desired folder on your networked drive
>   (i.e., computer 1's documents,
>   computer 2's documents, etc.). You may
>   have to physically copy everything
>   over, but then it will be on the
>   networked drive and everything should
>   work smoothly. That is, in the future,
>   Windows will go to the target location
>   whenever you look in "My Documents"

The article also notes that step 1 may not be required.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to this is to:

1. Go to the start menu
2. Right click on the my documents folder
3. Select properties
4. Change the target directory to the desired folder

Comment: This only works in Windows XP and earlier. Not sure about Vista though the option is gone in Windows 7 and later.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this on Vista, it might be similar on XP.

1. Right click on "Documents" in the start menu.
2. Change to the location tab
3. Edit the path.

Again this is Vista, it might be different on XP (try user Accounts).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put all of "Documents and Settings" on the D drive and not just "My Documents" and are willing to do a reinstall you can make an unattended install disk for XP and put "Documents and Settings" anywhere you please.

Here is a good tutorial:
http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/

Answer (score -1):

I use a domain at home and I setup a logon script to save it on my server.

I am considering getting rid of my server and going local and here are a few sites I was just reading....funny I see this question come up.

Gui Redirecting
http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/11/25/change-my-documents-folder-default-location-path-in-xp-and-vista/