# What's the best way to deal with the insane Windows XP home directories?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Default directory of Documents and Settings?](https://superuser.com/questions/2053/change-default-directory-of-documents-and-settings)

So I'm getting a little sick of the ridiculous home folder organization in Windows XP. I absolutely can't stand the name "My Documents" and I don't like putting my other main folders under that.

So this XP install around I put all my stuff in C:\Documents and Settings\Nathaniel and set the "My Documents" folder to Nathaniel\Documents, which of course messes with Explorer navigation with that folder (go to My Documents. Gah, I can't go up!).

Are there any ways in general to make the WinXP personal folder structure just less dumb? If only I were using *nix; the glories of /home!

(I know this is a little subjective, but... *help!*)

Comment: +1! This is one of the biggest reasons I switched to Linux!

Comment: I know this is much easier to change on Windows Vista and 7, but I'm not sure if there's a clean way to do it in XP. Good luck!

Comment: sounds like medication might be needed :-p

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/2053/change-default-directory-of-documents-and-settings .. related: http://superuser.com/questions/91609/winxp-putting-user-directories-on-secondary-partition .. i'm sure there are more

Comment: Close or CW, do you think?

Comment: @Nathaniel: don't worry about it.  i've voted to close; it needs 4 other close votes to be closed, and the community may disagree.  if *you* agree it should be closed, you're welcome to cast a vote to that effect as well, but it is not required.  CW status has no bearing on whether it's closed as a duplicate, but if you disagree with me, you can edit your question to emphasize parts of your question that make it different.  that may help the community decide to keep the question open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TweakUI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) lets you change which directories are for documents, music, video, and picures.  I did this for a while: I moved the music, pictures, and videos folders into the root of my profile rather than within the documents folder, and removed the "My" prefix from all of them.  It works pretty well, but occasionally you find software that doesn't deal with it properly because internally the programmer used hard-coded folder names.

You can also change just the "My Documents" folder without any software by right-clicking on it and choosing "Properties", then clicking "Move".

You can't rename "Documents and Settings", but you can create a [junction point](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) from `C:\Users` which maps to `C:\Documents and Settings`.  That way you can use the short *or* long version.

To have a system that natively uses, e.g., `C:\Users` rather than `C:\Documents and Settings` requires a new [unattended installation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314459).  The setting in the answer file (Winnt.sif) you're interested in is:

```
ProfilesDir="C:\Users\"
```

Comment: Genius thinking with the junction point!

Answer (score 3):

Voilá:

**Using Folder Redirector utility to redirect special folders in Windows XP**

**[Folder Redirector](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/folderredirector.htm)** can be used to relocate the special folders to a different path. This utility can relocate the following shell folders:

Desktop, Favorites, My Documents, My Music, My Pictures, Send To, Shared Documents, Shared Music, Shared Pictures, Shared Video, Start Menu, Startup, Temporary Internet Files, Common Startup, Common Desktop.

[image]

*Folder Redirector is freeware and portable (no installation required).*

... of course you can also change the path of 'special folders' in the registry.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Profile Relocator](http://software.bootblock.co.uk/?id=profilerelocator)

> is a step-based application that allows the re-locating of the Windows Users profile directory. Once re-located, any created profiles will appear in the new location in their entirety. The advantage to doing this allows profiles to be stored in a location that doesn't reside on the system drive, ensuring that profile data isn't compromised as a result of re-installation or system failure.
>
> Profile Relocator has been designed to
>   work with Windows XP, Vista, and 7.

More info and discussion at [Lifehacker- Profile Renamer](http://lifehacker.com/5480138/profile-relocator-moves-windows-profiles-to-a-new-location).

Haven't tried it, but may do in a few days. I'd be interested to hear how well it works.