# Can the default directiory be changed for multiple libraries at once (i.e. Documents, Pictures, Music)

Tags: windows-7, windows, home-directory, user-folders, folder-redirection

As explained in *[Change Default directory of Documents and Settings?](https://superuser.com/q/2053/358766)*, Windows has a built-in option for moving the default library folders to different directories. (Ex: moving ***My Documents*** from `C:\Users\Steven\Documents` to `D:\Libraries\Documents`)

I want to move multiple libraries in my user folder, (`%userprofile%`), from `C:\` to `D:\`, which means changing the location for ***Downloads***, ***Favorites***, ***My Music***, ***My Pictures***, ***My Videos***, and ***Saved Games***.

[image: User Folders from %userprofile%]

***Can I move multiple user libraries to another directory at once, or do they each need to be moved individually?***

Comment: There a reason you cannot just move each one individually?  Doing them all at once requires you modifying the default profile before the image is even built.

Comment: @Ramhound Moving each individually is a valid option. I wanted to know if there were a faster way to move multiple libraries to the same location, or if it had to be done individually

Comment: The faster way would invovle modifying the default profile, so the locations of these folders are already in their new location, and then create a new image and reimage the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries are collections of locations (folders, network shares, etc).  You don't move Libraries, you move folders and then update the Libraries to include that folder location.

The libraries are handled by using the [IShell­Library interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391719(v=vs.85).aspx), and IShellLibrary only handles one library at a time.  So the best you can probably hope for is a program that loops through each one and updates it to add the new path (and perhaps remove the old one).

Hopefully that helps explain, and gives you a starting point if you want to pursue coding yourself a solution.